# Adding new filter to an existing dashboard on Tableau

Tags: filtering, tableau-api, dashboard

I am new with **Tableau** and am trying as much as possible to use online forums/internet to find my solutions however it seems that I couldn't find my solution for my query.

I am trying to add a filter after I would have created a dashboard. I have added the Dimension in the Filter section on the sheet and also selected Show Filter. For some reason this is not being reflected on the Dashboard does anyone has experience something like this? Is it once you have created the dashboard you cannot add new filters to it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter to a worksheet in a dashboard by clicking the down arrow on the top right of the worksheet and then selecting Filters and the dimension you want to filter against.

[image]